# Long time Migration of macs (over 80 hours)

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, migration

I just changed my previous Mac (MacBook Pro dual core running Snow Leopard) to a MacBook Pro i7 with Lion, and after it is still migrating after 3 days (and according to the migration bar is about 60%, even if it indicates since it started between 60 - 80 hours. I wasn't aware of the reboot with one key (guess T) to use firewire, so it is using wifi...
It has been the worst nightmare I have gone through with a computer with any OS (yes, even Windows)

The worst thing is that the MacBookPro doesn't bring a CD/DVD so I could start the process on scratch usinqg FIREWIRE... and reinstalling the OS in case of any corruption.
I don't know what to do, but, waiting another 3 days is going to be a big issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I have had similar experiences with WiFi transfers involving large amounts of data. The good news is that if you are extremely patient it will probably work out OK. The other good news is that if you have not messed with the factory partitioning scheme it doesn't matter that you can't install from CD/DVD.

If you do choose to restart the whole process - by resetting your new machine to original configuration with the [Lion Recovery Partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718) - then a Migration using Target Disk Mode and the right FireWire 800 cable will probably take only an hour or so to complete.

Comment: You can also install lion from usb. Apple provides software to do that. Also your TM disk can be used to install Lion (once you backup from a Lion machine). I would go with what Adam suggested rather than waiting for WiFi transfer to complete. (if you connected ethernet cable it should be quite faster tho).

Comment: Or use an ethernet cable instead (and turn Wi-Fi off!), the Gigabit port is the quickest connection on both of them!

Comment: Note that reinstalling with Lion Recovery won't be very fast either, as it downloads around 4GB of installer files from Apple's servers...